# Как определить ближайшую дату по дню недели python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сегодня 21.09 Понедельник. След. занятие 22.09 (Вторник). Задача состоит в том, что бы получить дату ближайшего вторника (22.09)

Comment: что? ничего не понятно

Comment: Сегодня 21.09 Понедельник. След.занятие 22.09 (Вторник).
Задача состоит в том, что бы получить дату ближайшего вторника (22.09)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558535/find-the-date-for-the-first-monday-after-a-given-a-date

Comment: вас интересует именно ближайший или ближайший после сегодня / указанной даты ?

Comment: после указанной даты

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6558571/10941639.

Answer (score 1):

На скороую руку набросал так:

```
import datetime

WEEKDAYS = ('monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday')


def next_closest(from_date, search_day):
    if isinstance(search_day, str):
        search_day = WEEKDAYS.index(search_day.lower())

    from_day = from_date.weekday()
    different_days = search_day - from_day if from_day < search_day else 7 - from_day + search_day
    return from_date + datetime.timedelta(days=different_days)

print(next_closest(datetime.datetime.strptime('21-09-2020','%d-%m-%Y'),'tuesday'))
```

сильно не тестировал, но должно работать